# Prefix items in a comma delimited list stored in a property

Tags: ant

I have a property which has as its value a comma delimited list of strings representing numbers. For example,

test.property=one,two,three
It could be any list of numbers but the form will be the same.

I have a directory called, for arguments sake, 'reals'. 
Within it are subdirectories with names such as 'number.one', 'number.two' and 'number.three' etc and some other subdirectories I wish to ignore.

I would like to get a list of those subdirectories which correspond to entries in test.property

Something like

```
<dirset id="something" includes="${test.property}" dir="reals"/>
```

The problem here is that the items in the list defined by test.property would each need to be prefixed with 'number.' for this to work. I don't know how to do that, and that forms the first part of my question.

Is there any way around this using just the property I have described and not providing the task with a test.property list already in the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) task [`PropertyRegex`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) task, with something like this

```
<propertyregex property="${comma.delimed.nums}"
   input="package.ABC.name"
   regexp="\b(\w+)\b"
   replace="number.\1"
   global="true"
   casesensitive="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your dirset include the corresponding subdirectories edit + overwrite existing test.property with script task and builtin javascript engine :

```
<project>

<property name="test.property" value="one,two,three"/>
<echo>1. $${test.property} => ${test.property}</echo>

<script language="javascript">
 <![CDATA[
  var items = project.getProperty('test.property').split(',');
  var s = "";

  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   s += '*' + items[i] + ',';
  }

  project.setProperty('test.property', s.substring(0, s.length - 1));
 ]]>
 </script>   

<echo>2. $${test.property} => ${test.property}</echo>

<dirset id="something" includes="${test.property}" dir="C:\some\path"/>
<echo>Dirset includes => ${toString:something}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] 1. ${test.property} => one,two,three
[echo] 2. ${test.property} => *one,*two,*three
[echo] Dirset => number.one;number.three;number.two
```

If you want to create a new property instead of overwriting existing test.property use :

```
project.setProperty('whatever', s.substring(0, s.length - 1));
```

or

```
project.setNewProperty('whatever', s.substring(0, s.length - 1));
```

and use the new created property in include attribute of your dirset.

Comment: That's awesome. I've been using Ant for years and never knew scripting languages were available.

Comment: When using script task with builtin javascript engine you have full access to ant api and don't need any extra jars like f.e. antcontrib. Groovy is also recommended - you will need one jar for that - the groovy task is great.